# Graphical login of a local user remotely

Tags: fedora, gdm

I'm trying to automate a lab of computers running Fedora 17 (Gnome). I need to write a script that logs out the current local user on the system and logs in as a different user. The systems are currently using gdm. How can I login local users to a graphical interface via an SSH connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't interact with gdm, but you can login to the machines over SSH and invoke the startx command - it switches to a new tty and logs in the user.